# How to get selected value from dropdownlist in twigs

Tags: symfony, twig

I am working on an user profile's edit form, in which the country and its respective state drop downs are suppose to come with user's pre-selected value. I am struggling through the code but not getting any success.

I hardcoded it like this in twig file (*i want the dynamic value though but just for testing purpose i did it hardcoded like this*):

```
{{ form_widget(Form.country,{'attr':{'class':'input-block-level chzn-select','id':'select2_sample4','onchange': 'showState(this.value)', 'selected': '356'} }) }} {{  form_errors(Form.country) }}
```

`'selected': '356'` 356 is the country code, it must display India as selected. But no success, still i see the dropdown with no selected value.

Do anyone have idea how to do that?

Comment: Probably, something like `Form.vars.value.country`.

Comment: @Artamiel where should i suppose to write this in twig file? Sorry for the silly question but i am a newbie to it

Comment: Try replacing `'356'` with it. Or assign it beforehand to a variable with `{% set %}`.

Comment: no success, i replaced your piece of code with `"356"`

Comment: Why dont you try to simply echo it, to see if you get any output. `{{ Form.vars.value.country }}`

Comment: i am getting a blank page when trying to echo `{{ Form.vars.value.country }}`

Comment: `form.country.vars.value` should give you the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `'selected': '356'` as an attribute (in `attr` on the `<select>` element, which theoretically should result in something like `<select ... selected="356">` in your rendered form.

If I understand the question correctly, you want the `<option>` with value 356 to be selected inside the `<select>`. To do that, you can set the `value` option in the `form_widget()`, but *not* inside the `attr` options array, as you did, but instead like this:

```
{{ form_widget(Form.country,{'attr': {...}, value: '356'}) }}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, It works really fine with country....but not with state. I did like this: `{{ form_widget(Form.country,{'attr': {...}, value: Form.vars.value.country }) }}`